# How to convert GPA to German Grade?

Tags: gpa

My GPA of bachelor is about 3.0, and I just want to know how much it would approximately be in German Grade? Would it be lower than 2.7 in German Grade?
I have read other questions on this website, but none of them could help me, can you simply tell me how to convert GPA to German grading system?

Comment: Have you looked at **Grade Conversion Charts** section of the [Academic grading in Germany](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_grading_in_Germany) Wiki page?

Comment: Yes I read it completely but couldn't calculate my german grade

Comment: No. Don't even try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A GPA of 3.0 is (usually) exactly a B, which is coincidentally 3.0 in German Grade. Note that this is an estimate. Also, the correct way to calculate it would be not to convert the GPA directly, but to go through the transcript and re-compute the average using the German Grade.

This is a tool I found after a second of googling:
http://www.foreigncredits.com/Resources/GPA-Calculator/

It has grade tables and even a calculator that can do the math for you.

Comment: thanks for your information. I have also found that tool, but couldn't work with it, i guess i have to spend some more time with it

Comment: This is actually wrong. the correspondance is more:
A -> 1.0 (best possible grade),
B -> 2.0,
C -> 3.0,
D -> 4.0 (barely passing grade),
F -> 5.0 (failed),

The linked tool converts a german 2 to a GPA of 4.0 which would correspond to straight As, which is clearly wrong

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the specifics of your system, no, it's not possible to tell you how to convert *your* grades (or anyone else's) from one system to another.

However, what you do need to know about the German system is that it works "backwards": a 1 is the best grade, and 5 is a failing grade. The "1,0" corresponds to an A or A+ in an American style 4.0-system, and then moves in increments of 0.3 or 0.4. 4.0 corresponds to a D, and anything below that would be regarded as an F.

Comment: yes i knew about the point which you mentioned. thanks anyway